How can I retrieve Ethereum Message hash
Please how do I retrieve the message hash of an ethereum transaction without using the private key. Maybe using r, s,v values.

You can use ethers.js to instantiate the Transaction object using the transaction hash, like:
const tx = await provider.getTransaction(txHash);

Then, retrieve the message hash (or digest) using the Transaction.from(tx).unsignedHash string, like:
const messageHash = Transaction.from(tx).unsignedHash

Then, for verification, you can also recover the signer address by calling the recoverAddress function, passing the messageHash and the v, r, s values, like:
const recoveredAddress = ethers.recoverAddress(messageHash, { v, r, s });

Here's the sample code for the same:
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

(async () => {
    // Set up an Ethereum provider
    const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com"); // Replace with the RPC url as per your network

    // Transaction hash (replace with your transaction hash)
    const txHash = "0x6bf2412bc839d638864337bb4f3f423f303e0f5dead7ee9106edcf33edbd14a3";

    // Fetch the transaction
    const tx = await provider.getTransaction(txHash);

    if (!tx) {
        console.log("Transaction not found!");
        return;
    }

    console.log("Transaction Details:", tx);

    // Extract signature components (v, r, s)
    const v = tx.signature.v;
    const r = tx.signature.r;
    const s = tx.signature.s;

    console.log(`\nSignature components: v=${v}, r=${r}, s=${s}`);

    const messageHash = ethers.Transaction.from(tx).unsignedHash

    console.log(`\nMessage Hash: ${messageHash}`);

    const recoveredAddress = ethers.recoverAddress(messageHash, { v, r, s });
    console.log(`\nRecovered Address: ${recoveredAddress}`);
})();

